# Why are my tmux plugins not working on MacOS even after restarting the session?

Tags: macos, tmux

I installed tmux 3.3a using homebrew in my Mac (Ventura 13.4 OS). I installed tpm by cloning from https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm. I've added a theme plugin and reloaded the `~/.tmux.conf` file. I installed all the plugins with (prefix + I). I killed the exisiting tmux server and started a new one, yet I don't see my theme loaded or any of other plugins working.

I'm attaching screenshot of my plugin installation (I didn't see any error there either)

Here is my .tmux.conf -

```
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'fabioluciano/tmux-tokyo-night'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-logging'

### Tokyo Night Theme configuration
set -g @theme_variation 'moon'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

tpm plugin installation -

[image: tmux plugin installation]

Can someone help me with this?

This might feel like duplicate question but I tried all solutions. I tried killing the server and session instead of just exiting. I tried loading the config file from both inside and outside the tmux session, still the same. I deleted all plugins and installed them again assuming if previous installation went wrong but no change.

Comment: @pynexj `$TERM` value is `screen-256color`

Comment: @pynexj any suggestion what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at `tmux-tokyo-night`'s [source code](https://github.com/fabioluciano/tmux-tokyo-night/blob/cc3013cca97fcaacdba4ab8c3c4be72131c57490/src/palletes/moon.sh) and noticed it's using Bash's `declare -A` to define associative arrays. `declare -A` is a new feature in Bash **v4.0** but macOS' Bash is still at **v3.2**. I'm using Homebrew's Bash **v5.2** so it works for me.

To fix it:

1. Install latest Bash with Homebrew: `brew install bash`
2. Update `PATH` var in your bashrc <sup>(or other shell rc if you are not using Bash)</sup> and make sure Homebrew's path (`/usr/local/bin`) comes before `/bin` <sup>(macOS' Bash is at `/bin/bash`)</sup>.
3. Restart your terminal app to load your updated bashrc
4. Run `bash --version` to confirm it's `v5.2+`.
5. Kill old tmux sessoion and start a new one.

Note that you need to use [patched font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads) to correctly display some special chars/icons.

[image]

Comment: I checked and Homebrew's path is bfr macOS bash in `$PATH`. I changed it to new bash following this [link](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) but its still the same after reloading. Is there a way to make it work with zsh as that seems pretty latest `zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)`

Comment: what's "still the same after reloading"? did you confirm step 1~4's result is correct? are you using zsh or bash?

Comment: Actually it only worked for me after restarting the system but not after restarting tmux server. But tmux window bar still has unknown characters shown as `?`, I'm not sure why

Comment: glad to know it started working. for  weird `?` chars you need to install and use nerd fonts: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/

Comment: Thank you. I have been fighting this for awhile. Didn't consider it might be using bash behind the scenes while I'm using zsh